# How to implement Nadam in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

everyone. As mentioned, how can I implement Nadam optimizer with tensorflow?

What I can find is [tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam](https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Nadam), but after reading the API, i couldn`t find out how to use this in my training process. Could anyone help me with this api implementation, or how could i implement Nadam with tensorflow?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already Nadam implementation in tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/NadamOptimizer.

It is in contrib, meaning that the API can change, but you can use it just like any other TensorFlow optimizer.

Comment: Thanks, That`s what i haven`t found. Thanks for this information!@iga